# How to persistent background page in Safari extension

Tags: safari, safari-extension

I used `xcrun safari-web-extension-converter` to convert my chrome extension to safari extension but it built with this warning

```
Warning: Persistent background pages are not supported on iOS and iPadOS. You will need to make changes to support a non-persistent background page.
```

Also when using it on safari, it is showing these errors:

[Extension errors in safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJTDc.png)

How can I debug the errors in the extension? I'm not sure about the error but the persistent page warning seems to be a good place to start with. While searching for it in google, all I got is results for non-persistent background pages.

Do let me know if any more information is required.

PS:
The extension option in the "develop" menu of safari is also disabled due to `service_worker` failed to load error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [WWDC21-10104](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc21/10104):

> The background page is a web page that the browser loads to run your
> extension's background script. And this page allows your extension to
> handle events sent by the browser or other parts of your extension.
> But keeping this page loaded has a performance cost. It can use memory
> and power as if you were keeping one more tab open and running for
> every enabled extension. Keeping all these pages loaded all the time
> can be pretty wasteful. But you can make a background page
> non-persistent, which means the browser will only load it when your
> extension actually needs to do work, and the browser can later unload
> that page when it's been idle for some time. That way, the performance
> cost is only paid while your extension is doing something useful. This
> is important because background pages must be non-persistent on iOS,
> where system memory and battery life are especially at a premium. The
> web extension templates in Xcode already come with a non-persistent
> background page, so they're ready to run on iOS. But if you have an
> existing extension that uses a persistent background page like Sea
> Creator did, you'll need to change it to be non-persistent. And you
> can do that by adding that "persistent:" False key in the background
> section of your manifest.

So you can solve it by adding this to your `manifest.json`:

```
"background": {
    "scripts": [ "background.js" ]
    "persistent": false
}
```